# How to create stored procedure to get value of previous column Entry in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Database table : **UserTime**

```
UserTimeId int(pk)
LoginStatus nvarchar
```

`LoginStatus` stores only two pieces of information: `In` and `Out`

Ex:

```
UserTimeId    LoginStatus
--------------------------
    1           In
    2           Out
    3           In
    4           Out
```

I want to create a stored procedure to check what is the value of `LoginStatus` of the previous column.

In C# code I want to implement it as this:

```
if (StoredProcedureCheckLoginStatus='In')
{
   dothis...
}
else 
{
   do this....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE.  Sample attached:

```
WITH CTE as (
   SELECT 
     RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID),
     * 
   FROM HumanResources.Employee
 )
 SELECT
   [Previous Row].*,
   [Current Row].*,
   [Next Row].*
 FROM CTE [Current Row]
 LEFT JOIN CTE [Previous Row] ON 
   [Previous Row].RN = [Current Row].RN - 1
 LEFT JOIN CTE [Next Row] ON 
   [Next Row].RN = [Current Row].RN + 1
 WHERE
       [Current Row].EmployeeID = 5
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but it would make more sense if you used OP's variables.  `UserTimeId` instead of `EmployeeID`.. etc.

Comment: @paqogomez 27 A quick comment, hoping the user could figure out and fill the gaps :)

Comment: OP is a very new SO user, so thats a big hope. ;)  Doesnt look like it will happen, but this kind of thing is exactly where someone would swoop in and use your answer, but improve it, taking away your rep.  .. FWIW. :)

Comment: Doesn't bug me too much.  As long as we are growing the experience base.  Thanks for the heads-up.